# Convergence of $(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

So, I don't know how correctly show that,

$c(n) := \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\to 0\qquad\text{ as}\quad n\to\infty.$

Should I do this with limes or by $\forall \epsilon > 0,   \exists N(\epsilon)$ such that  $\forall n >= N(\epsilon) :| c(n) - c | < \epsilon$?

Comment: Can you use that convergent to zero times *bounded* converges to zero?

Comment: Could you just use a squeeze theorem argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to prove it (without knowing your background, you may or may not know all these tricks) is to consider the alternating series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$$

Using the Alternating Series Test, we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt n} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$. Thus the series converges, so for the series to converge, we must have $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n} \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

Standard argument is: For any given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = \lfloor{\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}\rfloor}+1\Rightarrow \forall n \geq N, |c_n| = \left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right| < \epsilon$, and the answer follows.